# How can I change my screen resolution without moving icons, like "Run in 640 x 480 screen resolution" compatibility setting

Tags: windows-8.1, resolution, compatibility, zoom

The title explains most of my question, but I'm going to go more into detail.

There is a game that I play that only runs in windowed mode at a certain resolution. Whenever I change my display resolution so I can play the game in more of a "full-screen" manner. It takes all the icons on my desktop and compacts them to the new resolution, and the rest that couldn't fit go to my external display. Which if you haven't realized yet, screws up all my icons which I arranged by myself. So now I have to rearrange them.

I noticed that in the compatibility tab in the properties menu there is a option to run the game in a "640 x 480" resolution. When I did that, it was too small for the game window, but. It didn't mess with the arrangement of my icons...

All it did was shift all the icons so that their positions relative to the top left of the screen were the same. So when the I closed the game and the resolution went back to 1080p, the icons were in the same place they were before.

Is there a way to do something like that, but with a different resolution of my choice? I don't want to use the magnifier because It doesn't actually change the resolution, and at certain zoom levels the pixels are stretched and it makes the game look weird.

Comment: Sorry, is your question just "how to keep my icons in the same place when changing screen resolution"

Comment: Does this help http://superuser.com/questions/290078/how-do-i-stop-windows-from-moving-desktop-icons

Comment: no, My question is, I want to change the resolution of my display, without the icons getting moved around because the resolution got smaller. I want an effect similar to the "Run in 640 x 480 screen resolution" setting in the compatibility tab when u open the properties menu for a .exe or shortcut. Is there like a special startup parameter?

Comment: No, the link isn't even a similar problem...

Comment: My Problem is, I'm playing a game that plays at a low res and I want to put it into a full screen mode by decreasing my display resolution. But when I do that through the display settings it rearranged all my icons, but when I use the "Run in 640 x 480 screen resolution" option in the compatibility settings for the application, it does exactly what I want, and will go back to 1080p when the game exits. The only thing is, the game window is larger than 640 x 480. So is there a way to make it zoom into a different resolution, without using the magnifier program.....

Comment: I had the same problem when I used Win 7 (my last Windows version before switching to Linux).  The solution I used was a utility that stores the desktop layout and restores it with a mouse click.  There are probably many such utilities and I don't remember which one I used.  However, ShellFolderFix (http://www.sevenforums.com/free-developer-programs-projects/40916-shellfolderfix-manage-folder-window-positions-size.html and http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11687/shell-folder-fix-remembers-window-locations-in-windows-7/), gets a lot of good press (don't know if it works on Win 8.1).